# Android complex listview from json

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a 2 screens app. When the users click a button on the main screen, he is taken to screen 2, where a listview awaits to be displayed with data from a database table.
I managed to retrieve the contents of the query and get it in json format. 
I also managed to display a simple listview using some information from the JSONArray.
But I would like to display more information in the listView Item. Not just one.
My code for populating the listview is:

```
    if (jArray!=null && jArray.length() > 0){
            JSONObject json_data; 
            try {
                int length = jArray.length();
                List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    listContents.add(json_data.getString("clientnume"));
                }
                ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
                myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(null, e.toString());
            }                   
    }
```

I know there must be something at setAdapter, but I have no idea how to code it differently. Probably I would need also a multidimensional array..?!?!
I started by adding a new layout (just for the listview item) where I added an imageview and 3 TextViews. But I do not know how to set that layout as the layout for my listview, and also populate the textviews with data from my JSONArray.

Please help me.

IMPORTANT: my JSONArray comes from a mysql DB through POST.

Comment: override getview and inflate a cusotm row for each row.

Comment: You are doing it wrong, there shouldn't be Json objects in the adapter class or in the activity class

Comment: @Yume117 Well... where should the JSON object be? And why should it not be here?

Comment: @Raghunandan I understand it sounds easy to you, but I have no experience whatsoever doing what you suggest. This is why I ask. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to make a custom lisview, so you may need a custom adapter.
Here is a tutorial you may use in order to solve your issue :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Basicaly, create a layout as you started, make a list with your datas (Hashmap) and your adapter will do the rest.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are retrieving value form SQLite database then why you are converting it into JSON instead just get the cursor object and pass it to your adapter, write a Custom Adapter which extends CursorAdapter and your job done , check this link http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Comment: I get the JSON array data from a mysql DB through POST. So no SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Doing your way can work ok. But you must be aware that if you have something to change in your appli or juste add a fonctionnality, that will be hard since all the code is centered at the same place (if someone else has to modify your code it ll be painfull too ...)

Exemple : your can have a **JsonParser** class that get tue json stream over the network

```
public class JSONParser {
    /**
     * PRIVATE ATTRIBUTES
     */
    // log
    private static final String TAG     = JSONParser.class.getSimpleName();
    //
    static InputStream          is      = null;
    static JSONObject           jObj    = null;
    static String               json    = "";

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Then your **objects** that ONLY must descibe (human, cat, contact, ...) and do some intern work.

To finish you can create class that manage the objects, convert then from/to json ... and so

The download should be held in some **other thread** (service, asynctask, loader, .. etc) in the adapter you should only use the data that are downloaded, converted to object, stored and ready. And do not store json datas unless you have specific needs. Convert them to usable data before storing them